# config angular-cli nginx subdirectory /example

Tags: nginx, angular-cli

I want to serve a angular application at the url my_url/exemple.

this my nginx config :

```
location /example/ {
    alias /pwd/example/dist/;

    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

}
```

and this is my build command : ng build -bh example

when I go to the my_url/example I have a redirect to my_url/example/example and of course angular said me : 
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'example'

If the location is / is work : I can go to my_url/example and the application work. But in production / is taken by a django application.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 4):

To allow this location to handle the URI `/example` without a trailing `/`, you could remove the trailing `/` from the `location` and `alias` statement.

Also, your `try_files` statement contains a number of strange terms, and two default actions where only one is permitted. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

If the `index.html` file is at `/pwd/example/dist/index.html`, it needs to be represented by the URI `/example/index.html`.

Suggested configuration:

```
location /example {
    alias /pwd/example/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /example/index.html;
}
```

If your application works at `/` at the moment, but not at `/example/`, you may need to look at the application, and ensure that it pulls its resource files (css, js) with the correct URI prefix also.

Comment: Does this also supports handling routes with the /#/route ?

Comment: "If your application works at `/` at the moment, but not at `/example/`, you may need to look at the application, and ensure that it pulls its resource files (css, js) with the correct URI prefix also." -- This is exactly my question...the `index.html` page is looking for the scripts just by name, e.g. `<script src="runtime-es2015.0811dcefd377500b5b1a.js" ...>`, so the web server can't find them. Is this a change I need to make in the Angular config at build time to say, "look for scripts under `/example` instead? Or is there a config directive I can put in Nginx to make it do this?

Comment: I believe I figured it out, at least for Angular 9: use `--deploy-url` in your build command, e.g. `ng build --prod --deploy-url /example/`